# Rails place radio_button and label in the same row

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to place the radio_button and label for the button on the same horizontal level. Here's the logic in the view:

```
         <div class="row">
           <div class="span1">
             <%= f.radio_button :flg, 'Y', :class => "radio-buttons" %>
             <%= f.label :flg, 'Y', :value => 'Y' %>
           </div>
           <div class="span1">
             <%= f.radio_button :flg, 'N', :class => "radio-buttons" %>
             <%= f.label :flg, 'N', :value => 'N' %>
           </div>
         </div>
```

And the generated html (for just one button):

```
<div class="span1">
<input checked="checked" class="radio-buttons" id="device_flg_y" name="device[flg]" type="radio" value="Y">
<label for="device_flg_y">Y</label>
<div class="span1">
```

However, this puts the label below the radio-button. How do I put them on the same level, while keeping the label? I know I can replace the label with a span, but the span isn't clickable and related to the radio-button like the label is.

Comment: Can you post the css for the label, input, radio-buttons classes (if you defined anything)?

Comment: only thing I've done is input.radio-buttons has a vertical-align:top setting. other than that, using bootstrap as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `display: inline-block` to either the label, input or radio-buttons class, should fix it and show the label and radio button on the same line.

Comment: That worked, just adding that I applied inline-block to the label. Thanks!